# Reading an article and tokenizing it

Tags: java, token, filereader, tokenize

The goal is to read a file then tokenize every word in the article and store back in an element. So later I can turn that into an array in a different class and remove some words from it. The problem is that that i do not know if its reading and tokenizing the article correctly. also im not sure if i should use a String to store the tokenized article after its been read and tokenized.

```
public class Articles{

    private String article;

    public Articles() {

        article = "";
    }

    public String  getArticle(){

        return article;
    }

    public void readArticle( String file) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String words;
        while((words = br.readLine()) != null) {
            article = words;
            getArticle();
        }

        }
    public void tokenize() {
        StringTokenizer strt = new StringTokenizer(article);
        while (strt.hasMoreTokens()) {
                article = strt.nextToken();
                getArticle();
            }
    }


    public void print() {

        System.out.println(article);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to check whether your program works correctly

Comment: @fakedrpanda You can reduce the code complexity by storing the already tokenized string in an array, else you'll have to again tokenize the string in another class.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example of what you could do**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Articles{

private String article;
private ArrayList<String> tokens;

public Articles() {
    article = "";
    tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public String  getArticle(){

    return article;
}

public ArrayList getTokens(){

    return tokens;
}

public void readArticle( String file) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String words;
    while((words = br.readLine()) != null) {
        article = words;
        tokenize();
    }

    }
public void tokenize() {
    StringTokenizer strt = new StringTokenizer(article);
    while (strt.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokens.add(strt.nextToken());
        }
}


public void print() {

    System.out.println(article);
}
}
```